# Function de js externa em jsp

Tags: javascript, java, twitter-bootstrap, java-ee, bootstrap-3

Olá,

Pretendo utilizar uma function de js externo, uma typeahead do js,
e chamar ele na input de minha jsp, porém não está trabalhando de acordo.

Importação da js que faço na minha jsp.

```
<script src="javascript/todospaises.js" type="text"></script>
```

Quanto ao código Html, a input, que tem que receber a function do js.

@Html

```
<input type="text" id="input-paises" class="typeahead" placeholder="Países">
```

E, o código da function do js externo, ou seja, de outro arquivo.

```
var $input = $("#input-paises");
                        $input.typeahead({source:[‘Brasil, Estados Unidos, Inglaterra, Alemanha’,
                        ]});
```

Porém, a typeahead não trabalha quando, é utilizado a function de outra js. A function só é efetiva, quando está na mesma jsp,

```
<script> var $input = $("#input-paises"); $input.typeahead({source:[‘Brasil, Estados Unidos, Inglaterra, Alemanha’, ]}); <script>
```

Ou seja, apenas quando está na jsp. Apenas quando o trecho de código js fica na jsp.

Obrigado!

Comment: Na página gerada pelo JSP, quando você clica em "View Source" e clica na referência do arquivo externo JS, o que acontece? Dá erro 404 ou abre o JS normalmente?

Comment: @RafaelB., abre normalmente.

Comment: @All, Alguma dica para o mesmo?